# Windows clients - GPO, deny network access but allow rdp

Tags: windows, networking, group-policy

In our organization, we have domain group which are added to local administrators group at clients computers.

I need to make GPO to deny that domain group access from network but enable them RDP.
There is setting for deny access from network but it denies also RDP.

Thanx in advice.
Predrag.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'access from network'?

Comment: `There is setting for deny access from network but it denies also RDP.` No, it does not.

Comment: Thanx for replying. that setting also denies RDP. Already checked several times... When unlink that gpo, user from that group can access to every computer from network and can RDP...

Comment: Right now I checked. When this setting applied and when user try RDP, error message displys **The system administrator has restricted the types of logon (network or interactive) that you may use.**... Any advice...?

Comment: @Predrag - It's unclear what you are asking.  Please edit your question with details that will allow others to understand what you are trying to prevent when you say "deny access from network".  Perhaps you change it from what you are trying to modify in the GPO to what you are expecting to happen network wise.

Comment: in my organization, we have a domain group (named LocalAdmins) which are applied with GPO as members of local administrators group at every client workstation. Because of security, it is needed to give them a permission to administrate a clients workstations, to give them ability to connect with RDP to clients but to deny them to connect to administrative shares. I already create separate GPOs for adding them to local administrator group and to deny them to connect to administrative shares, but that **Deny access to this computer from the network** also denies RDP! Any advice?

Comment: Why the restriction on administrative share? as when logged in, they can do anything, as they are local admin anyway.

Comment: @yagmoth555... to prevent local admins to connect to client workstations throu network admin shares... thay can admin clients workstations only when they are login locally. I wanted to deny network shares but enable RDP...

Comment: Admin share let them view remote eventviewer, computer management, etc.. so its why I wonder why you remove them diagnostic power, in the end you remove them power to help your user. If its to deal with an abuse case, deal with the guy, not the whole team

Answer (score 1):

To control access you probably want to use the setting in my first screenshot, not the setting in my second screenshot.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Joeqwerty, thank you for helping. This is good idea but by default, **Access this computer from the network** on client have Everyone, Administrators, Users and Backup Operators. If apply only this domain group, than all others are gone. I think that all default users/groups needs to insert in GPO with my domain group. Right? One other thought... Is it posible to allow this domain group (LocalAdmins) to RDP only for members of this group?

Comment: Dear Joeqwerty, I will mark your post as answer but I made new OU where this policy didnt applied and local admins can connect only on theirs workstations. That isnt what I wanted but it is ok until I found new solution. Thanx.